# Google Calendar Api CalendarList List Method Not Returning Self Owned Calendars

Tags: javascript, rest, google-calendar-api, fetch-api

So I'm using Calendar's calendar list REST method to retrieve all of the users calendar's. This endpoint to be specific: `https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList`

And this is working fine for 99% of my users. Unfortunately some have reported that my app isn't showing them the calendars that they own, particularly their 'main' calendar.

Upon further investigation I've tried passing the `minAccessRole` parameter with a value of `owner` and this returns an empty array for these users.

Any ideas? I'm not sure why these users aren't getting self owned calendars back from the api.

Heres my code. Originally I was just calling the endpoint once to get all of the users calendars, but I then tried breaking it out into two calls to try and specifically get self owned calendars:

```
getAllCalendars = (token) => {
    let url = "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList?";

    let params = {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    };

    let p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      fetch(url, params)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
          let lists = data.items;
          console.log("all cals");
          console.log(lists);
          resolve(lists);
        });
    });

    return p;
  };
```

For the users in question, this method is returning all calendars except self owned ones.

Heres my code for trying to get only self owned calendars:

```
getMyCalendars = (token) => {
    let url =
      "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList?" +
      new URLSearchParams({
        minAccessRole: "owner",
      });

    let params = {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    };

    let p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      fetch(url, params)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
          let lists = data.items;
          console.log("my cals");
          console.log(lists);
          resolve(lists);
        });
    });

    return p;
  };
```

And this is returning `[]` for the problem users

Just to reiterate and try and concisely sum it up: The List method of the rest api is not returning calendars where the `accessRole` is `owner` for some users, but is working as expected for most users.

Comment: That's strange, since a user's primary calendar [cannot be removed](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37188?hl=en#zippy=%2Cdelete-a-calendar-cant-be-undone%2Cdelete-all-events-in-your-primary-calendar). Can you check whether the users can access their primary calendar in the UI?

Comment: Thanks for the reply lamblichus. I don't think the calendars were removed, they just aren't being returned by the list end point for some reason. In the real calendar.google.com site the users can see their owned calendars still. And in my app I can see their primary calendars, they just can't see their own.

Comment: Can you provide the code related to the requests you are making?

Comment: Done, thanks for the help

Comment: Thanks, have you checked whether the calendars are retrieved via `Try this API`? [CalendarList: list](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/list) (while logged in with any of the problem users, of course).

Comment: I have, same result. Calling with no min access role gets l.non self owned calendars, calling with min access role returns an empty array.

Comment: Looks like a very strange behaviour, and I cannot reproduce this. I'd consider contacting [Workspace support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213).

Answer (score 1):

> So I'm using Calendar's calendar list REST method to retrieve all of the users calendar's.

The CalendarList method does not return all of the users calendars.  The user needs to add them the user can also remove them there is no controlling what a user may or may not have done to their CalenarList.  A user can have access to a calendar which does not appear in CalenadrList, as this would have to have been specifically added to the calendarList which is not 100% guaranteed to happen when a user is granted access to a calendar.

For the most part a user "should" have at the very least a primary calendar in their calendarList but this does not appear to happen across all users and there is no information from google as to why.  Your best bet would be to insert the primary calendar in to the CalendarList for this user which will then fix your issue.

## What is calendarList and how does it work?

The [calendarList.List](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/list) is mealy the list that appears on the bottom left hand side of the UI window. There is no guarantee that a user will have anything in this list as it depends upon how the user added the calendar to the list in the first place. The user could also have deleted it form the list. The UI tends to do it automatically but if it was added programmaticlly it will probably not appear it the users calendarlist.  So you should not be relying upon the calendarlist to contain a list of all the calendars a user has access to. please see [Events and calendars](https://developers.google.com/calendar/concepts/events-calendars#calendar_and_calendar_list)

[image]

All users do however have a **primary** calendar you can always do calender.get on `primary` and you will get back the primary calendar for that user.

You should never depend upon the CalenarList to contain anything, again its just a UI element and it is far from prefect.

You may also want to consult the issue forum with relation to CalendarList and how it is currently implemented [Issue forum](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:191627%2B%20calendarlist)