# Can't get a list owned by me in Google Calendar API

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

Using Google Calendar API v3 to get the calendar list.
However, some users are not able to retrieve their own owner's calendar.

I tried using the Try this API for CalendarList#list to retrieve it,
but it did not return the owner's calendar.
https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/list

However, if the user specifies calendarId as primary in CalendarList#get,
it can be retrieved successfully.
https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/get

Do you have any advice for me?

Comment: Can you share the code/request that you are using? The primary calendar ID is just the users email. Can you share the error message/response?

Comment: I just tried a list request with the "try this api" on the link you copied, and on both a workspace and gmail account the primary was listed. Is there any other detail you can give to try and reproduce this?

Comment: @iansedano sure you could delete something from the calendarList and still keep your access on the calendar that would recreate it.  CalendarList is just a UI item it does not contain a list of **all** the calendars a user has access to there is no endpoint to list all of the calendars a user has access to.  Please check my answer

Comment: Interesting @DaImTo, though AFAIK you can't delete your primary calendar. I have tried unselecting the primary calendar in the UI so I can't see the events, but it still shows up in the list request.

Comment: @iansedano yeah im wondering if the issue with primary is that is a service account or that OP is confused as the primary calendar is actually the users email address as the calendar id.  They havent actually shown us any output to prove their claim.

Comment: Possibly, just ran a test on a test account (didn't want to risk it!) to check if it was somehow possible to delete a primary and I can't find a way. All "deleting" the primary does is remove all events.

Answer (score 0):

> Can't get a list owned by me in Google Calendar API

Answer: There is no endpoint which will return a full list of all calendars Owned or that the user simply has access to. As this endpoint does not exist the answer to your question is you cant so its working as intended.

In actually you have misunderstood what the calendarlist is. See below

## What is calendarList and how does it work?

The [calendarList.List](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/list) is mealy the list that appears on the bottom left hand side of the UI window. There is no guarantee that a user will have anything in this list as it depends upon how the user added the calendar to the list in the first place. The user could also have deleted it form the list. The UI tends to do it automatically but if it was added programmaticlly it will probably not appear it the users calendarlist.  So you should not be relying upon the calendarlist to contain a list of all the calendars a user has access to. please see [Events and calendars](https://developers.google.com/calendar/concepts/events-calendars#calendar_and_calendar_list)

[image]

All users do however have a **primary** calendar you can always do calender.get on `primary` and you will get back the primary calendar for that user.

Comment: @DalmTo Thanks for the reply. Do you mean that my own email address (primary) calendar is not listed? I tried passing the value of owner to the minAccessRole parameter, but it returns an empty array.

Comment: I found a similar problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66936660/google-calendar-api-calendarlist-list-method-not-returning-self-owned-calendars

Comment: Google does not gareentee that anything will be in CalendarList and there is a small subset of users who do not have a primary calendar in the calendarlist either.  You should simply do a calendarlist.insert and add it for them.   you may also want to check https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:191627%2B%20calendarlist  but really i would stop tyring to relly upon calendarList unless your application is doing the inserts.